# Remove last 3 characters on alternating lines

Tags: shell

I need to remove the last 3 characters in alternating  lines. I have

```
 36960
32768
40800
16384
22656
4096
```

I need to have output like

```
 36960
32
40800
16
22656
4
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

An awk solution:

```
~$ cat file
 36960
32768
40800
16384
22656
4096
~$ awk '{if (NR%2){print $0}else{print substr($0, 0, length($0)-3)}}' file
 36960
32
40800
16
22656
4
```

Comment: Thanks Guys . You are real guys ..Hats off the solution worked for me . One more Fan for AWK command

Comment: +1: You can even use `gsub`. `awk '!(NR%2){gsub(/...$/,"")}1' file`

Answer (score 1):

Preceding a "sed" command with a "step" amount will do what you want. This looks like X~Y, which will match every Y'th line starting with line X.

```
sed '2~2 s/...$//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide the number by 1000 and store the answer into an integer.

As such:

int a = 32768/1000;

The value stored in a will be 32

For the Alternate lines:

Use a loop that increments by 2 (assuming you store those numbers in an array)

```
for(a=0;a<6;a=a+2)
{ 
    place code described above here; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk program that does it:

```
if (NR % 2 == 0) {
  print gensub(/(.*).../, "\\1", "g"); 
}
else
{
 print $0
}
```

If I run it like this I get the shown output:

```
:> awk '{ if (NR % 2 == 0) { print gensub(/(.*).../, "\\1", "g")} else { print $0 }}' << EOL
>  36960
> 32768
> 40800
> 16384
> 22656
> 4096
> EOL
 36960
32
40800
16
22656
4
```